# How to convert this String array to array so that I can print all the results coming from a for loop to a string separated by commas

Tags: java, arrays, string, arraylist, collections

```
         if(CoverageNames.size()>0) {

            StringBuffer tmp = new StringBuffer();
            for(int i =0; i<CoverageNames.size();i++) {
                tmp.append(CoverageNames.get(i).getText());
                tmp.append(";");
            }
            List<String[]> covNamesListReport= new ArrayList<>();
            String[] CoverageNamesListReport={"CoverageNamesListReport",tmp.toString()};
            covNamesListReport.add(CoverageNamesListReport);
            String CovName= covNamesListReport.toString();
            CoverageReportList("CoverageNames", CovName);
        }
```

Coverage Report List is a method that accepts two string arguments.
I'm learning right now so any other approaches are also welcome.

Comment: I think you should be more clear: which is the String array you want to convert? What is your goal? And, most important, what have you tried?

Comment: `String result = Arrays.stream(foo).collect(Collectors.joining(","));` is how I'd do it.

Comment: It’s not clear what you want. Why do you create an array of two elements, add it to a list, just to call `toString()` on that list? If you want the two items to be separated by a comma, just use `String result = "CoverageNamesListReport, " + tmp;` There’s a general solution for arrays, i.e. `String.join(", ", array)`, but there’s no point in using an array when you have just two elements and the first is even a constant string. Alternatively, you could just do `tmp.add("CoverageNamesListReport, ");` before the loop, then `tmp.toString()` does already yield the final result.

Answer (score 0):

When converting `List<String[]>` to string in line `covNamesListReport.toString();`, the contents of the inner arrays is NOT displayed as expected and look like `[[Ljava.lang.String;@726f3b58]` because the arrays' `toString` method is invoked.

To display the contents of the inner strings properly, nested `List<String>` could be used:

```java
List<List<String>> covNamesListReport = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> CoverageNamesListReport = Arrays.asList("CoverageNamesListReport", tmp.toString());
            
covNamesListReport.add(CoverageNamesListReport);
String CovName = covNamesListReport.toString();
// -> [[CoverageNamesListReport, AAA;BB;CCC;]]
```

or `Arrays.toString` could be used just to convert a nested array:

```java
List<String> covNamesListReport= new ArrayList<>();
String CoverageNamesListReport= Arrays.toString(new String[] {
    "CoverageNamesListReport", tmp.toString()
});
            
covNamesListReport.add(CoverageNamesListReport);
String CovName= covNamesListReport.toString();
// -> [[CoverageNamesListReport, AAA;BB;CCC;]]
```